# Php Session Array - Updated Session Array not showing up in the listbox

Tags: php, arrays

What I am looking for is the listbox to be refreshed from the $_Session data. First inital load, it loads up fine.  When I select the option that I want to be removed and then click on the submit. The $_Session modifys perfectly.

```
--- INDEX.php ---
<select name="listbox" size="5" height="500px;">
<?php
$array_length = count($_SESSION['listmodify'][0]);
if(isset($_SESSION['listmodify'][0])){
  for ($i = 0; $i < $array_length ; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $_SESSION['listmodify'][0][$i]['sku'] .','. $_SESSION['listmodify'][0][$i]['qty'] . '">' . $_SESSION['listmodify'][0][$i]['sku'] . ' - ' . $_SESSION['listmodify'][0][$i]['qty'] . '</option>';
  }
}

?>

</select>
```

--- DELETE.php ---

```
$listsku = $_POST['listbox'];
$key = array_search(trim($listsku), array_column($_SESSION['listmodify'][0],"sku"));
unset($_SESSION['listmodify'][0][$key]);
$_SESSION['listmodify'][]=array_values($_SESSION['listmodify'][0]);
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

These images show what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what I need to do to get the listbox to show the updated $_Session data?

Comment: Most likely has something to do with this line... $_SESSION['listmodify'][]=array_values($_SESSION['listmodify'][0]). You're creating a new key in listmodify and adding an array to it. So it won't show up in session[listmodify][0]

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks. I did not even see that. It works.